# Usage of CWWirelessProfile and CoreWLAN

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am attempting to put together a small utility to allow users to connect to a wireless network in a university setting. The original solution was a combination of shell scripts, apple scripts, and a touch of Obj-C. This had it's own problems. I've since taken it upon myself to try to do the same in a single set of code.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072749/programmatically-created-airport-connection-persistence) was incredible useful. However the sample was for a PSK security mode. The documentation that Apple provides has not been the [greatest](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/CoreWLANFrameworkRef/CWWirelessProfile_h/Classes/CWWirelessProfile/). The [example code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CoreWLANWirelessManager/Listings/CoreWLANController_m.html) provided was also lacking if you want to create a profile on behalf of previously provided credentials.

I get that I can use setPassphrase, but what about a username or even a domain? I can't find any reference to either of those properties.

Lastly, I attempted to tweak the sample code to my purposes. I came across two things. The first was upon changing the securitymode, it complained about a domain property not being configured/existing.

The second (and more irritating since the changes didn't matter) : After compiling and actually running the code, I throw an error at `CWConfiguration *conf = [airport configuration];` The error is `*** -[NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil`. From what I can see in xcode, airport is holding en1 at the 0 of the array. There's content, so I don't understand why it claims nil.

My goal is to create a little utility that a person can provide their enterprise credentials for, I take those credentials and create a WPA2_Enterprise wireless profile and save it to their preferred networks. Also during this process I hope to add a pair of certificates to their keychain that are tied to a radius server. Not sure if the order of operations would affect my ability to create a wireless profile that uses a username, userpassword, and domain. (My knowledge of the network is limited. If I need to go learn more in order to do this, I'm willing.)

Thanks for reading

***a later edit***

Playing around with it, once I added a minimum of two networks into the preferred networks area by hand, I stopped getting the nil error. However the app requests permission to edit a fake keychain item while adding it's own next to it. Also, the profile still does not appear in the preferred networks list in System Preferences. I feel I'm missing something obvious and oh so close to getting it.

Comment: I wouldn't want to run an unknown application on my Mac just to connect to some wireless network. Allow me to download the needed certificates and install them myself. Installing a certificate is as simple as double-clicking it, anyway.

Comment: Agreed, but I can't treat it that way. Currently, you can connect to the network by selecting it and putting in your credentials. The certs, then prompt for trust and that should be that. However, for some people this is too complicated. Hence, trying to write a little utility/applet/whatever to do the work for them. It truly is a matter of 1 or 2 clicks to connect as opposed to 5 clicks. Besides, I needed to start somewhere with learning this stuff.